# Firing up Terminal from an Automator Workflow?

Tags: terminal, automator

I quite often use the **python -m SimpleHTTPServer** command in the Terminal to fire up a webserver for testing apps.  Having just learned the basics of the Automator, I figured this would be a great use for it - having added the following as a service I can now right-click on a folder and have a webserver launch pointing at that folder.

```
cd $1
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

The only problem I have, is the lack of output from the workflow.  Doing it manually I have a Terminal window displaying the requests coming in and enabling me to Ctrl+C to end the webserver.

The Automator workflow is silent and I have to open Activity Monitor and quit Python to close it.  Is there a way to have it run the script in a Terminal window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured out how to do it myself based upon adapting the following article.

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050827164648766

Added a line in to run the python command:

```
on run {input, parameters}
  tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    if (the (count of the window) = 0) or ¬
     (the busy of window 1  = true) then
      tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "n" using command down
      end tell
    end if
    do script "cd \"" & (POSIX path of ¬
     (input as string)) & "\"" in window 1
    do script "python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000" in window 1
  end tell
  return input
end run
```

Comment: Replace the 'tell application "System Events"' block with just "do script". A "do script" command with no parameters will open a new terminal window. Simulating keystrokes is an unreliable means to script an application; only do it as a last resort, if there's no means to directly tell it to do what you want.

Comment: That "do script" command won't work will all valid pathnames. Remove the quotes from the shell command string (\") and use `quoted form of (POSIX path of (input as string))` instead. `quoted form of` knows how to correctly quote all characters that need to be quoted for shell commands.

Answer (score 4):

If you like using Automator try the [Growl](http://growl.info/) Notifier in Automator (below is an example). [Growl is extensible](http://growl.info/documentation/developer/) to almost any application/script/service on OS X. It works really well for showing output for just about anything imaginable.

[image: Auto Growling]

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with **python**, still no output anywhere.