# Opening a file with command-line bin through Finder

Tags: automator, bash

I wish to use `mp3blaster` (installed through `MacPorts`) via Finder. I want to double-click an mp3 file and get it opened in `mp3blaster`. But I haven't been able to do so. I created an app and, in another try, a service in Automator, using the following script:

```
/opt/local/bin/mp3blaster $1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get info on your .mp3 file and change the associated app.

Go to `cmd-i` of your app, click the drop-down of "Open with:" .. Select `other` and navigate to your directory. You will have to select `Enable : All Applications` to be able to click on the mp3blaster app.

Comment: The problem is that `mp3blaster` is not an app but a bin. So I cannot do what you suggest.

Comment: I think you might have to create an apple script and then have the files associated to the apple script.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to, unsuccessfully. Could you please tip me on that?

Answer (score 1):

Start Automator, create a workflow with a *Run AppleScript* action and save it as an application.

[image]

Then select any mp3 file, type <kbd>Cmd-I</kbd> and change the default application to the application saved before.

Comment: Thanks, @patrix. But it doesn't work. Same error message. (Of course, if I run `/opt/local/bin/mp3blaster` from a bash shell it works.)

Comment: What happens if you run it inside Automator and look at "Results" afterwards?

Comment: See here: http://i49.tinypic.com/2rxgmf6.jpg

Comment: Ah, of course, you can't run interactive commands with a "Run Shell Script" action.

Answer (score 0):

Use $@ to refer to a file being passed to a shell script in Automator:

```
/opt/local/bin/mp3blaster $@
```

or

```
/opt/local/bin/mp3blaster "$@"
```

Comment: I get the error, "The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error."

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed how to do it using `AppleScript` instead of `bash`. (I followed this example: [Firing up Terminal from an Automator Workflow?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25471/firing-up-terminal-from-an-automator-workflow))

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        if (the (count of the window) = 0) or ¬
            (the busy of window 1 = true) then
            tell application "System Events"
                keystroke "n" using command down
            end tell
        end if
        do script "/opt/local/bin/mp3blaster \"" & (POSIX path of ¬
            (input as string)) & "\"" in window 1
    end tell
    return input
end run
```

Comment: However, this only works for single files taken as input. How could I alter the script to parse multiple files?